API on AWS using MySQL randomly reporting System.Exception: Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list'
I have a strange issue occuring on AWS I have an API running on .net in a elastic beanstalk.  It is working perfectly fine just now but randomly in say a week it will all of sudden start failing.
The api is being called to update data in entity framework and works with MySQL using the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL library and .net 8.
The error that just starts happening is this System.Exception:
Unknown column 'XX' in 'field list' 

When I google this it states that it MySql error that it cant find the column XX which is a date column.
The strange thing is everything seem to work fine if I flip the server over to a backup and it all starts working again?
Has anyone experienced this as all the googling I have done says it because the field name is wrong but it is right and when I flip the server it starts working again.  I am at a complete loss as to where this is occurring.
additionally I have 2 portal beanstalk which use the same Entity framework, repository code and business logic these never fail...

just to add I have no configuration for this column in my dbcontext it is using out of the box migration

Did yo update the Core library to a newer version?  If so you may need to run migration to fix issue.  Net 8 is still a little buggy and maybe going to Net 7 is better.
